# Debian Virtualbox cannot SSH and ping

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine

I have a Debian 7 VM inside VirtualBox. I did not install the VM, I just got it so I have no control over the initial configuration. I'm trying to have ssh access from the local machine to the VM, have an Internet connection on the VM and also have other VirtualBox VMs ping it. I have other Ubuntu VMs that see each other. How can I fix my Debian box? Here is what I have:

The VirtualBox VM has 2 networks: a) Adapter 1 - NAT; b) Adapter 2 - Host-only Adapter vboxnet0;

```
$ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:03:51:4e  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe03:514e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11631 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7774 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5449513 (5.4 MB)  TX bytes:629951 (629.9 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:2c:8a:7a  
          inet addr:192.168.56.33  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe2c:8a7a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5626 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:866971 (0.0 KB)  TX bytes:737635 (737.6 KB)

$cat /etc/network/interfaces
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
      address 192.168.56.33
      netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Ifconfig on the host is (other machines can connect to it):

```
vboxnet0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:00:27:00:00:00  
          inet addr:192.168.56.1  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:682 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:200449 (200.4 KB)
```

I want my server to be accessible using a static IP (192.168.56.33). At this point I can't even SSH to my box from my local host machine. How can I fix this? This is certainly a networking problem and not a ssh problem since ping also fails.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the information you provided is unclear.
Try changing the VM's network adapter settings (via VirtualBox) to "Bridged Mode".
That should allow the traffic to flow both ways.

Comment: I changed the settings to Bridge mode for Adapter 2 and I still can't ping it. I have Ubuntu Vagrant boxes that have the exact config but work the way I want (obviously it has a different IP). That's why I used this setup.

Answer (score 0):

I found an ugly hack that fixed my issue: reversed the interfaces. For some reason they seem to be detected in the wrong order and my configs set NAT for the gateway and DHCP for the Host-Only one. here is my new /etc/network/interrfaces.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
      address 192.168.56.33
      netmask 255.255.255.0
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```